# Android app that captures location of field staffs (for monitoring)

Tags: android, offline, gps

I am currently working on a project that requires me to come up with a monitoring system to monitor our field staffs. Our field staffs work in rural communities that are very far apart, remote and no access to mobile networks; hence, making supervision very difficult.

Can you please suggest an Android app that works offline to capture their location at any given time?

The app should be able to

- record the exact location of these field staffs offline and without their knowledge, but can be seen online by the admin whenever the phone is synchronized
- work offline

Comment: In many countries such an application would be illegal as you have specified monitoring the position of people without their knowledge - only governments _and Apple it seems_ are allowed to do this!

Answer (score 1):

How would you install such an app on the many  phones of your staff, without their knowledge? So you probably need to give them company phones, train  them how touse them, and ask for consent *and* some cooperation (opening these apps at least once, or from time to time) to get a more reliable signal.

According to the description, The [OsmAnd App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.osmand) and its  [Tracker Plugin for Telegram](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.osmand.telegram) does this. It is based on an opt-in scheme, that means The user must agree to share his/her location via the [Telegram](https://telegram.org/) messenger app which must also be installed on the phone. 
So you could give them a company phone with these apps preinstalled.

I haven't tried these in conjunction though.

Search for [OsmAnd on android.stackexchange.com](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=osmand) for more info about the app. It's GPL'ed!